# Azure Devops - Error: Access Denied: <user> needs the following permission(s) on the resource Materialization to perform this action:

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I have a user in Azure DevOps who is trying to add another user to a User Storie in Azure Boards, but when he finishes typing the user and autocompletes, that user in the field automatically appears the message

> Azure DevOps - Error: Access Denied:  needs the following permission(s) on the resource Materialization to perform this action: Edit identity information, Manage group membership

I tried to change the user's permissions in another permission group by setting them to contributor without any success.

Can you help, please?

Set user in Contributors;
Create another group of permissions;
User is not Stakeholder, is Basic

Comment: Refer to this ticket with the same issue: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Error-message-when-trying-to-add-a-Team-/10616251 It seems that the issue is from the azure devops itself.  Many users have the same issue.

Comment: Can you try to input the complete user name and then select the account? Then you can check if it can work.

Comment: The error occurs when typing the username to be assigned to the story and clicking on the list to autocomplete. If you enter the user manually without automatic filling, it will work as an alternative solution but we have many users in the company and it is really not effective this way as it is not possible to memorize all the users.

Comment: Fully understand your situation. The method can be a temp workaround. The issue is investigated by the Azure DevOps Product Group. If there is any update, I will update here too.

Comment: I am also having this same issue. I have tried to enter manually and tab out or enter and click on user. Both result in the error described. I tried to assign from story details as well as from the backlog page by right clicking on the story --> edit --> assign to. This started maybe 2-3 weeks ago.

Comment: @silvathiago25 Get the update from PG team, they have  reverted the change that was causing the issues with assigned to. You can check if it can work now.

Comment: thanks for your update. I'll check.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this ticket: [Error message when trying to add a Team Member](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Error-message-when-trying-to-add-a-Team-/10616251#T-ND10626985)

The cause of the issue is that the Product Team made some changes to boards a few weeks ago. it leads to issues of identity.

Now, Product Team has reverted the change that was causing the issues with assigned to.

You can try to assign to the users in the work item again and check if it can work.